# Running latexmk from PHP server

Tags: latexmk, php

I am trying to generate a voucher using `latexmk` through a PHP shell execution command function. I've tried all alternatives, i.e. `exec(), shell_exec(), passthru(), popen()` without luck. To get a feeling of the error I used `$latexmk = passthru("latexmk -pdfxe -diagnostics $rec_fil");` The log I get is:

When I suspected that it is a `user` related problem, I ran the script from a PHP interactive and it produced the pdf output desired.

I have also tried the `-f` option for `latexmk`, without luck.

With the error above, I only get the `aux` and `fdb_latexmk` files, without information for a novice like me to understand if there is a problem:

aux file content:

```
\relax
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

fdb_latexmk file content:

```
# Fdb version 3
["xdvipdfmx"] 0 "001140.xdv" "001140.pdf" "001140" 0
  "001140.xdv" 0 -1 0 "xelatex"
  (generated)
  "001140.pdf"
["xelatex"] 1637578209 "001140.tex" "001140.xdv" "001140" 1637578209
  (generated)
  "001140.xdv"
  "001140.log"
```

After redirecting STDOUT/STDERR to a log file, this is the content:

```
Set environment variable BIBINPUTS='.:'
Set environment variable TEXINPUTS='.:'
Given='001140.tex', tex='001140.tex', base='001140', ext= .tex, source=''
Rule classification:
  Requested rules:
    xdvipdfmx
  No pre-primaries
  Primaries:
    xelatex
  Post-primaries:
    xdvipdfmx
  No inner-level one_time rules, as expected
  No outer-level one_time rules
Latexmk: Rules after start up for '001140.tex'
===Rules:
  [dvifilter]: 'external' '' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.dvi' '001140.dviF' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.dvi': 0 -1 0 'latex'
  [dvips]: 'external' 'dvips %O -o %D %S' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.dvi' '001140.ps' '001140'
 0 0
    '001140.dvi': 0 -1 0 'latex'
  [latex]: 'primary' 'latex  -recorder %O %S' '' 1 '001140.tex' '001140.dvi' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.tex': 0 -1 0 ''
  [print]: 'external' 'NONE $lpr_pdf variable is not configured to allow printing of pdf files %O %S' 'if_source' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [psfilter]: 'external' '' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.ps' '001140.psF' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.ps': 0 -1 0 'dvips'
  [update_view]: 'external' '' 'do_update_view 1 1 0 1' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [view]: 'external' 'start start acroread %O %S' 'if_source' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [xdvipdfmx]: 'external' 'xdvipdfmx -E -o %D %O %S' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.xdv' '001140.pdf' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.xdv': 0 -1 0 'xelatex'
  [xelatex]: 'primary' 'xelatex -no-pdf -recorder %O %S' '' 1 '001140.tex' '001140.xdv' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.tex': 0 -1 0 ''
Rule classification:
  Requested rules:
    xdvipdfmx
  No pre-primaries
  Primaries:
    xelatex
  Post-primaries:
    xdvipdfmx
  No inner-level one_time rules, as expected
  No outer-level one_time rules
Rule classification:
  Requested rules:
    xdvipdfmx
  No pre-primaries
  Primaries:
    xelatex
  Post-primaries:
    xdvipdfmx
  No inner-level one_time rules, as expected
  No outer-level one_time rules
Latexmk: Rules after initialization
===Rules:
  [dvifilter]: 'external' '' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.dvi' '001140.dviF' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.dvi': 0 -1 0 'latex'
  [dvips]: 'external' 'dvips %O -o %D %S' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.dvi' '001140.ps' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.dvi': 0 -1 0 'latex'
  [latex]: 'primary' 'latex  -recorder %O %S' '' 1 '001140.tex' '001140.dvi' '001140' 1 0
    '001140.aux': 1637583680 32 3985256e7290058c681f74d7a3565a19 ''
    '001140.tex': 0 -1 0 ''
  [print]: 'external' 'NONE $lpr_pdf variable is not configured to allow printing of pdf files %O %S' 'if_source' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [psfilter]: 'external' '' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.ps' '001140.psF' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.ps': 0 -1 0 'dvips'
  [update_view]: 'external' '' 'do_update_view 1 1 0 1' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [view]: 'external' 'start start acroread %O %S' 'if_source' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [xdvipdfmx]: 'external' 'xdvipdfmx -E -o %D %O %S' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.xdv' '001140.pdf' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.xdv': 0 -1 0 'xelatex'
  [xelatex]: 'primary' 'xelatex -no-pdf -recorder %O %S' '' 1 '001140.tex' '001140.xdv' '001140' 1 0
    '001140.aux': 1637583680 32 3985256e7290058c681f74d7a3565a19 ''
    '001140.tex': 0 -1 0 ''
Rule classification:
  Requested rules:
    xdvipdfmx
  No pre-primaries
  Primaries:
    xelatex
  Post-primaries:
    xdvipdfmx
  No inner-level one_time rules, as expected
  No outer-level one_time rules
Make: doing pre_primary and primary...
  Make1 xelatex
     remake
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
No new source files for rule 'xelatex':
Removing no-longer-needed dependent '001140.aux' from rule 'xelatex'
Removing no-longer-needed dependent '001140.tex' from rule 'xelatex'
Latexmk: Rules after run:
===Rules:
  [dvifilter]: 'external' '' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.dvi' '001140.dviF' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.dvi': 0 -1 0 'latex'
  [dvips]: 'external' 'dvips %O -o %D %S' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.dvi' '001140.ps' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.dvi': 0 -1 0 'latex'
  [latex]: 'primary' 'latex  -recorder %O %S' '' 1 '001140.tex' '001140.dvi' '001140' 1 0
    '001140.aux': 1637583680 32 3985256e7290058c681f74d7a3565a19 ''
    '001140.tex': 0 -1 0 ''
  [print]: 'external' 'NONE $lpr_pdf variable is not configured to allow printing of pdf files %O %S' 'if_source' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [psfilter]: 'external' '' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.ps' '001140.psF' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.ps': 0 -1 0 'dvips'
  [update_view]: 'external' '' 'do_update_view 1 1 0 1' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [view]: 'external' 'start start acroread %O %S' 'if_source' 2 '001140.pdf' '' '' 0 0
    '001140.pdf': 0 -1 0 'xdvipdfmx'
  [xdvipdfmx]: 'external' 'xdvipdfmx -E -o %D %O %S' 'do_viewfile' 2 '001140.xdv' '001140.pdf' '001140' 0 0
    '001140.xdv': 0 -1 0 'xelatex'
  [xelatex]: 'primary' 'xelatex -no-pdf -recorder %O %S' '' 1 '001140.tex' '001140.xdv' '001140' 0 0
Rule classification:
  Requested rules:
    xdvipdfmx
  No pre-primaries
  Primaries:
    xelatex
  Post-primaries:
    xdvipdfmx
  No inner-level one_time rules, as expected
  No outer-level one_time rules
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Apparently `latexmk` or children have removed the `aux` and `tex` files as no longer needed dependents for the compilation when run from the server, i.e. PHP.

That is about the only thing I notice from the log.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I've never seen anything remotely like this.  What's very suspicious is that after the line "Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex' ..." there is none of the expected output.  In particular,  xelatex appears not to have been run.  It's almost as if latexmk and/or xelatex aren't the expected programs. Some basic questions: 1. Is a latexmkrc file in use to configure latexmk? 2. What version of latexmk are you using, and under what OS and tex distribution? 3. Try the same run with cleaning out all auxiliary files first.  4. Is there a 001140.log file?

Comment: One other thought:  What happens if you run latexmk from an ordinary command-line prompt, i.e., without involving anything to do with PHP? I suspect there will be no problems, but it's important to know explicitly.

Comment: At the top of the listing there's no line with latexmk's version information.  Can you confirm the line is really missing.

Comment: @JohnCollins: Thanks for the comment and follow-ups. It is weird is it not! 1) No rc file is used, the user is actually `daemon`. 2) Version 4.75 under TeXLive 2021, updated daily and running under Ubuntu 20.04, PHP 7.3 under Scriptcase (Which might come with quirks to accommodate Scripcase). 3) No log file was produced on those runs, just the two files I have mentioned. 4) It runs fine from all ordinary command-lines, tried bash, dash, sh, zsh using sudo -u daemon latexmk with options. The line you refer to in third comment is actually missing.. Follow-up next comment ...

Comment: @JohnCollins: What I have put is actually all that I've got. That redirection helped formatting the output, before that my eyes got crossed trying to figure out what's going on without carriage returns.

Comment: @JohnCollins: I think there is nothing wrong with latexmk, it is just designed to operate under normal conditions and the PHP installation doesn't provide such conditions. I say that because I actually solved the problem by using a shell script with a bash shebang! It turns out that the dash shell which PHP spawns to do the execution of shell commands is just too messed up for operation of latexmk. While $PATH is setup to have all bin directories, there is something else missing which I couldn't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a PATH setting-related problem.

I am not sure if this is a very special case to PHP 7.3 used in Scriptcase or it is a general PHP-related issue.

While `latexmk` does get executed and generates `aux` and `fdb_latex` files. For some unknown reason to me, it can't continue the compilation due to PATH ambiguous setting; read the below paragraph.

I did pass the compilation to an `sh` script where PATH is set at the top of the script to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` then did some simple shell processing before calling `latexmk` with desired options. As per PHP requirements, STDOUT and STDERR must be redirected. Without defining the PATH, compilation will fail.

PHP calling code:

```php
$tempdir = exec('mktemp -dt "latex.XXXX"');
$texfile = "$tempdir/001140.tex";
$stdoe = "$tempdir/stdoe.log";
$cmd = "$tempdir/latexmkit.sh";
exec("$cmd -t $texfile -l $stdoe");
```

The script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

while getopts t:l: flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    t) texfile=${OPTARG} ;;
    l) oelog=${OPTARG} ;;
  esac
done

latexmk -pdfxe -cd $texfile >>$oelog 2>&1
```

I am not a shell programmer, someone please improve the above to be more safe and secure for general use.

Comment: This looks like a good work around and a good answer. Nevertheless, I am still very puzzled by the behavior you see, and it's worth investigating in depth. Normally if there is a path problem, one gets actual error messages. Similarly, if some expected files are not found, latexmk reports it. But you don't see that. I suggest you contact me at the e-mail in the latexmk documentation and we can try to work out what's happening.